# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Tags: c#, asp.net

So far this is what I have.

```
protected void CategoryRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Object dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;

        // code to pull catid out of dataItem
    }
```

Here's an example of what dataItem contains after running in debug:

> dataItem = { TextCategory = "Radiation (Release or Contamination)",
>   catid = 4, TextResult = "Refer to emergency plan and report under code
>   332.54(A)" , IsReportable = True }

I want to pull the catid out of the object. I have tried casting it, but all attempts to cast it have been unsuccessful. My goal is to use this catid for a nested repeater's databind.. something like this:

```
using (NERAEntities entities = new NERAEntities())
{
    var Questions = (from x in entities.Questions
                   where x.CategoryID == catid
                   select new { QuestionText = x.Text }); 


    QARepeater.DataSource = Questions;
    QARepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: First of all, you're not showing the actual type of that object, nor do you show the code where you attempted to cast it, nor do you show the code that produces that exception since there is no indexing in the code you've posted at all. Could you *please* post some *relevant* code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the DataItem doesn't really have a type per se (it's an Anonymous class). You would need to use this instead:

```
dynamic dataItem = e.Item.DataItem ;
int catId = dataItem.catid ;
```

Obviously, this would fail at runtime if the actual object doesn't have a `catId` property.

Comment: You don't even necessarily need the `as dynamic` you could write it as `dynamic dataItem = e.Item.DataItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the type of the object you're using is called DataItem, try this:

```
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataItem dataItem = (DataItem) e.Item.DataItem;

        // code to pull catid out of dataItem
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try:

```
protected void CategoryRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, 
    RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        int? catID = row["catid"] as int;
    }
}
```